# My job executes an arbitrary number of times even though only scheduled once

Tags: c#, jobs, job-scheduling, hangfire

- Hangfire 1.6.17
- SQL Server 2016 (13.0.4206.0)

I have a C# console application that uses OWIN to host a Hangfire server as follows:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder aAppBuilder)
    {
        //How we want to use Hangfire
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                           .UseSqlServerStorage("HangfireConnectionString")
                           .UseConsole(new ConsoleOptions
                                       {
                                           BackgroundColor = "#0d3163",
                                           TextColor = "#ffffff",
                                           TimestampColor = "#00aad7"
                                       });

        //Read the settings file
        SettingsIni iniSettings = new SettingsIni(GeneralHelper.GetAppPath() + "settings.ini");

        //Dashboard
        aAppBuilder.UseHangfireDashboard(iniSettings.HttpServer.Path, new DashboardOptions
                                                                      {
                                                                          AppPath = "/",
                                                                          Authorization = new[]
                                                                                          {
                                                                                              new HangfireAuthorizationFilter()
                                                                                          }
                                                                      });

        //Server
        BackgroundJobServerOptions serverOptions = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
                                                   {
                                                       Queues = GeneralHelper.GetQueueNames(iniSettings).ToArray()
                                                   };

        aAppBuilder.UseHangfireServer(serverOptions);

        //Ensure our recurring tasks are running if required.
        if (iniSettings.Behaviour.DoPlatformManagerInit) TpHangfireJobsManager.Initialise();
    }
}
```

As part of the application starting up I add a fire and forget job as follows:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<TpHardLinkAttachmentsForEmailMessagesWatchDog>(aX => aX.ExecuteJob(null, new TpHardLinkAttachmentsForEmailMessagesWatchDogParamsInput
                                                {
                                                    ForYear = 2017
                                                }));
```

and the method being executed is:

```
public override void ExecuteJob(PerformContext aContext, TpHardLinkAttachmentsForEmailMessagesWatchDogParamsInput aParams)
{
    Trace.WriteLine($"Params: {aParams.ForYear}");
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(aParams.ForYear, 1, 1);
    DateTime endDate = new DateTime(aParams.ForYear, 1, 31);

    //Start with a huge record id so we can work backwards
    long currRecId = int.MaxValue;

    //Keep getting records until we are done
    while (true)
    {


        //Find all records that have to be processed. We start with the highest record id in the year and then work backwards until we run out of record
        long idLast = currRecId;
        Trace.WriteLine($"Id Last: {idLast}");
        List<EmailActivityTableModel> recordsToProcess = _EmailActivityDomainService.GetWhere(
                                                                                        aR => aR.Id < idLast &&
                                                                                              aR.Created >= startDate &&
                                                                                              aR.Created <= endDate &&
                                                                                              (
                                                                                                  aR.ExternalIdKind == ExternalIdKindEnum.Family ||
                                                                                                  aR.ExternalIdKind == ExternalIdKindEnum.Individual
                                                                                              ) &&
                                                                                              (
                                                                                                  aR.ExternalId != "" ||
                                                                                                  aR.ExternalId != "-1"
                                                                                              ) //Ensure we have an external identifier
                                                                                    ).OrderByDescending(aR => aR.Id)
                                                                                    .Take(5).ToList();

        //We are done if we did not find any records
        if (recordsToProcess.Count == 0)
            break;

        aContext.WriteLine("Process {0} records.", recordsToProcess.Count);
        Trace.WriteLine($"Record Count: {recordsToProcess.Count}");

        foreach (EmailActivityTableModel emailActivityRecord in recordsToProcess)
        {
            aContext.WriteLine(emailActivityRecord.Id);

            currRecId = emailActivityRecord.Id;
            Trace.WriteLine($"Curr Rec Id: {emailActivityRecord.Id}");
        }

        //TESTING - Bail after the first iteration so 5 records
        return;
    }
}
```

All the method is doing is ultimately reading some records from the database and ouputting the primary key. What I am seeing is that method get called multiple times (the amount varies from each run of the console application) and I see the following:

[image]

I only see a single succeeded task in HangFire though:

[image]

I am getting **no exceptions** (note all 5 iterations complete each time) so the job is not getting restarted because of that.

So my question is why is my ExecuteJob() getting called so many times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering this for completeness.

It turned out I was getting an exception bit it was not showing in my logs. I eventually tracked it down by adding the [coloured console logger](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/configuring-logging.html#console-logger).

I am using a third party package called [HangFire.Console](https://github.com/pieceofsummer/Hangfire.Console) which has an issue with the attribute **DisableConcurrentExecution** as detailed [here](https://github.com/pieceofsummer/Hangfire.Console/issues/45). Swapping that attribute for the **Mutex** and now all is well.

Comment: Where is `DisableConcurrentExecution` and `Mutex` attributes?

Comment: @PreguntonCojoneroCabrón Follow the link under the word "here" which will lead you to https://github.com/pieceofsummer/Hangfire.Console/issues/45 which has a link to the Mutex attribute code.